# React Ant design tag click and showing to text area

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-typescript

I'm using my react typescript project for  **[Ant design,](https://ant.design/components/tag/)**

this is my conflict, I wanna click on the tag and its display to text area,  so when I type the text and then click tag next type text and click tag,

[image]
anyone know solution?

**[stazkblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pqp2iu?file=index.js)**

Thanks

**code here**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { Comment, Avatar, Form, Button, List, Input,Tag } from 'antd';
import moment from 'moment';

const { TextArea } = Input;

const CommentList = ({ comments }) => (
  <List
    dataSource={comments}
    header={`${comments.length} ${comments.length > 1 ? 'replies' : 'reply'}`}
    itemLayout="horizontal"
    renderItem={props => <Comment {...props} />}
  />
);

const Editor = ({ onChange, onSubmit, submitting, value }) => (
  <>
    <Form.Item>
      <TextArea rows={4} onChange={onChange} value={value} />
    </Form.Item>
    <Form.Item>
      <Button htmlType="submit" loading={submitting} onClick={onSubmit} type="primary">
        Add Comment
      </Button>
    </Form.Item>
  </>
);

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    comments: [],
    submitting: false,
    value: '',
  };

  handleSubmit = () => {
    if (!this.state.value) {
      return;
    }

    this.setState({
      submitting: true,
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        submitting: false,
        value: '',
        comments: [
          ...this.state.comments,
          {
            author: 'Han Solo',
            avatar: 'https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/ODTLcjxAfvqbxHnVXCYX.png',
            content: <p>{this.state.value}</p>,
            datetime: moment().fromNow(),
          },
        ],
      });
    }, 1000);
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      value: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { comments, submitting, value } = this.state;

    return (
      <>

       <div>
      <Tag color="magenta">magenta</Tag>
      <Tag color="red">red</Tag>
      <Tag color="volcano">volcano</Tag>
      <Tag color="orange">orange</Tag>
      <Tag color="gold">gold</Tag>
      <Tag color="lime">lime</Tag>
      <Tag color="green">green</Tag>
      <Tag color="cyan">cyan</Tag>
      <Tag color="blue">blue</Tag>
      <Tag color="geekblue">geekblue</Tag>
      <Tag color="purple">purple</Tag>
    </div>
        {comments.length > 0 && <CommentList comments={comments} />}
        <Comment
          avatar={
            <Avatar
              src="https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/ODTLcjxAfvqbxHnVXCYX.png"
              alt="Han Solo"
            />
          }
          content={
            <Editor
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
              submitting={submitting}
              value={value}
            />
          }
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: so as i understood, do you want to insert a specific text that is bind to the tag in the text area whenever its been clicked?

Comment: @m5khan yes, like my attached image , so when i type on the text area and next click  on the tag its should display  on the text area

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add a click handler to the `Tag` and whenever it's clicked you append its value to the `textarea` :

```
addTag = e => {
  const txt = e.target.innerHTML;

  this.setState(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    value: `${prevState.value} <${txt}> `,
  }));
}


<Tag onClick={this.addTag} color="magenta">First Name</Tag>
<Tag onClick={this.addTag} color="red">Last Name</Tag>
<Tag onClick={this.addTag} color="volcano">NIC</Tag>
<Tag onClick={this.addTag} color="orange">FAX</Tag>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pqp2iu-jtqgvf?file=index.js

Comment: Hi, thanks for your solution and valuable time ,its worked for me

Comment: Hi @Taki did you know this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67501190/react-typescript-tag-details-onclcik-not-showing-on-the-sun-editor

Answer (score 1):

yes as already mentioned by Taki, you have to attach event listeners on your tags to listen to the click event and then handle that click event accordingly.

Alternatively if you also want to bind some data on the tag, then you can use `data-` attributes on html elements. read [using data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

```html
        <div>
          <Tag color="magenta" data-value="John" onClick={this.onTagClick}>
            First Name
          </Tag>
          <Tag color="red" data-value="Cena" onClick={this.onTagClick}>
            Last Name
          </Tag>
          <Tag color="volcano" data-value="123123" onClick={this.onTagClick}>
            NIC
          </Tag>
          <Tag color="orange" data-value="999999" onClick={this.onTagClick}>
            FAX
          </Tag>
        </div>
```

```js
  onTagClick = e => {
    const dataValue = e.target.dataset.value;
    this.setState(previousState => ({
      value: previousState.value.concat(dataValue)
    }));
  };
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pqp2iu-ehjkvr?file=index.js

Comment: @m5kjan HI, thanks for your solution and valuable time

Comment: Hi @m5khan did you know this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67501190/react-typescript-tag-details-onclcik-not-showing-on-the-sun-editor