# React Typescript tag details onclick not showing on the sun editor

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd, react-typescript, suneditor

I'm using my react typescript project for Ant design,

this is my conflict, I wanna click on the tag and its display to **[Sun editor content area](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pqp2iu-ynivmu?file=index.js)** so when I click the tag display the text area but it I cant to add on the sun editor
any solution for this?
Thanks

**[stazkblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pqp2iu-ynivmu?file=index.js)**

code here

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { Comment, Avatar, Form, Button, List, Input,Tag } from 'antd';
import moment from 'moment';
import 'suneditor/dist/css/suneditor.min.css';
import SunEditor from "suneditor-react";
const { TextArea } = Input;

const CommentList = ({ comments }) => (
  <List
    dataSource={comments}
    header={`${comments.length} ${comments.length > 1 ? 'replies' : 'reply'}`}
    itemLayout="horizontal"
    renderItem={props => <Comment {...props} />}
  />
);

const Editor = ({ onChange, onSubmit, submitting, value }) => (
  <>
    <Form.Item>
      <TextArea rows={4} onChange={onChange} value={value} />
    </Form.Item>
    <Form.Item>
      <Button htmlType="submit" loading={submitting} onClick={onSubmit} type="primary">
        Add Comment
      </Button>
    </Form.Item>
  </>
);

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    comments: [],
    submitting: false,
    value: '',
  };

  handleSubmit = () => {
    if (!this.state.value) {
      return;
    }

    this.setState({
      submitting: true,
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        submitting: false,
        value: '',
        comments: [
          ...this.state.comments,
          {
            author: 'Han Solo',
            avatar: 'https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/ODTLcjxAfvqbxHnVXCYX.png',
            content: <p>{this.state.value}</p>,
            datetime: moment().fromNow(),
          },
        ],
      });
    }, 1000);
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      value: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  addTag = e => {
    const txt = e.target.innerHTML;
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      value: `${prevState.value} <${txt}> `,
    }));
  }

  render() {
    const { comments, submitting, value } = this.state;

    return (
      <>

       <div>
      <Tag onClick={this.addTag} color="magenta">First Name</Tag>
      <Tag onClick={this.addTag} color="red">Last Name</Tag>
      <Tag onClick={this.addTag} color="volcano">NIC</Tag>
      <Tag onClick={this.addTag} color="orange">FAX</Tag>
    
    </div>
        {comments.length > 0 && <CommentList comments={comments} />}
        <Comment
          avatar={
            <Avatar
              src="https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/ODTLcjxAfvqbxHnVXCYX.png"
              alt="Han Solo"
            />
          }
          content={
            <Editor
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
              submitting={submitting}
              value={value}
            />
          }
        />

        <SunEditor

                                                        autoFocus={true}
                                                        width="100%"
                                                        height="150px"
                                                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                                                        onClick={this.onSubmit}
                                           /*       defaultValue={value}*/
                                                        setOptions={{
                                                            buttonList: [
                                                                // default
                                                                ['undo', 'redo'],
                                                                ['bold', 'underline', 'italic', 'list'],
                                                                ['table', 'link', 'image'],
                                                                ['fullScreen'],
                                                                ['codeView']
                                                            ]

                                                        }}
                                                    

                                                        setContents={value}
                                                    />

      </>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));


  [1]: https://www.npmjs.com/package/suneditor-react
  [2]: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pqp2iu-ynivmu?file=index.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE 13-MAY-2021**

using state in sun editor will trigger race problem between `handleChange()` and `addTag()`, there is a chance the state will be replaced by old state.

To get rid of it, use the sun editor reference to manipulate the content.

For adding new text and place it horizontally instead of vertically, they have a `insertHTML()` function which will respect the html content without adding new `<p>` in the first place.

Updated Code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pqp2iu-axacak?file=index.js

- **Create editorRef**

```js
constructor() {
  super();
  this.editorRef = React.createRef();
}
```

- **Apply the ref to sun editior**

```
<SunEditor ref={this.editorRef} ... />
```

- **Remove `handleChange()`**, leave it to sun editor to handle it by itself
- **append text by using `insertHTML()`**

```js
addTag = e => {
    const txt = e.target.innerHTML;
    this.editorRef.current.editor.insertHTML(`{${txt}}`);
};
```

---

**OLD content**

`<` and `>` have special meaning in sun text editor which is representing html tags like `<p>` `<a>` etc and it will be hidden from the editor.

Therefore, when you apply `<Firtname>` to the editor, it will disappear. To be able to display it, I suggest you to use mustache syntax `{}` which is used by SendGrid, Twilio template as well.

Other than that, `handleChange` in sun text editor will return you the content directly so there is no need to get it from event target.

Here is the forked version of yours with mustache template

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pqp2iu-axacak?file=index.js

```
handleChange = content => {
    console.log(content);
    this.setState({
      value: content
    });
};

addTag = e => {
    const txt = e.target.innerHTML;
    console.log(txt);
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      value: prevState.value.replace(/<\/p>$/, '') + `{${txt}}</p>` // remove the last </p>, append the new content, add back the </p> to avoid new line
    }));
};
```

Comment: Thank for your time and its working so any idea about  tag display vertically  on the editor  like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pqp2iu-jtqgvf?file=index.js

Comment: What do you mean by vertically? I can only see a empty comment box in stackblitz. Can you show me the picture?

Comment: Ic, it is a different topic. as Sun Editor append each new element with `<p></p>`, so when you type abc and choose {FirstName}, it will be `<p>abc</p><p>{FirstName}</p>`. Need to read the library to see how to twist the behaviour.

Comment: May reply you here if i find a way to do it.

Comment: HI, Hello Buddy, nice, again thank for your valuable time and I got an issue , when click two time on the tag tag label looping  here the image https://imgbb.com/ any idea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232317/discussion-between-core114-and-mic-fung).

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pqp2iu-snguth?file=index.js Updated the code.
I think it is their bug. I added focus on the input field first before inserting text to bypass the problem. I think you should better consider another rich text editor, sun editor doc and support are limited. need to dig into their source code to see what is happening .